# Delete user if not verified - MondoDB & Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mern

I'm struggling to utilise the mongo DB TTL using mongoose to delete a user automatically if they have not verified their account within 24 hours.

userModel.js File

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
    },

    email: {
      type: String,
    },

    password: {
      type: String,
    },

    emailVerified: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    tokens: {
      verify: {
        emailVerifyToken: String,
        emailVerifyExpiry: Date,
      },
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

userSchema.methods.verifyEmail = function (id) {
  const verifyString = crypto.randomBytes(12).toString('hex');

  this.tokens.verify.emailVerifyToken = crypto
    .createHash('sha512')
    .update(verifyString + id)
    .digest('hex');
  this.tokens.verify.emailVerifyExpiry = Date.now() + 60 * 1000; // set to 60 Seconds for testing

  return verifyString + id;
};
```

Get info from clientside, create newUser, pass ID to verifyEmail, generate a string, hash the the string with user ID, then return the string with ID, create url, send email and save user.

authController file register function:

```
 try {
    const newUser = new userModel({
      username,
      email,
      password,
    });

    const verifyString = newUser.verifyEmail(newUser.id);
    const verifyUrl = process.env.VERIFY_URL + verifyString;

      sendEmail({
        to: newUser.email,
        subject: 'Verify Account',
        body: '<a href=${verifyUrl} clicktracking=off>Verify Account</a>'
      });

    await newUser.save();
   
    res.status(200).json({
      authentication: true,
      message: `Account registered successful, verification email sent to ${newUser.email}.`,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
```

Questions:

Now that I saved the user, send a email, if user verify within 60 second then "emailVerified" is set to true and tokens object is set to undefined which is then deleted for "this" document only.

I have two options, either create a auto function which check each documents in user collection and delete them or or create a auto function which runs each time a user registers and deletes the document if not verified after 60 seconds.

Code below works when I manually enter on mongosh in mondogb compass but not sure how to add within the schema or add code inside authcontroller register function. Id prefer the schema.

```
  db.users.createIndex(
    { 'tokens.verify.emailVerifyExpiry': 1 },
    {
      expireAfterSeconds: 0,
      partialFilterExpression: { emailVerified: false },
    }
  );
```

Thanks